# Building a twitter user db

Tags: twitter, graph, relational-database, neo4j

I'm building a simple twitter graph and I'm having a discussion with other members of the team about how to implement it.

I think that the A option is the best due to performance and simplicity, but other members(the project leader specially prefers C) aren't convinced due to inexperience with the platform.

I've never used a graph in a production application so I don't have a strong argument when the PL starts comparing it to the C option.

So I ask you which option would you choose based on your experience?

Elements:

- Twitterusers
- Lists
- Interests

A) neo4j graph

Nodes:

- twitteruser
- list
- interest

Relations:

- follows(user1, user2)
- member_of(user, list)
- interested_in(user, interest)

B) Same graph, but splitted in smaller graphs to increase performance.

C) Simple neo4j graph and a relational db to query the data.

.graph:

Nodes:

- twitteruser

Relations:

- similarity(user1, user2)

.relational db: the nodes of A will translate to tables and the
relationships will be done through many to many keys.

Answer (score 5):

From what you described I personally don't see any reason for options B and C. The scenario you describe looks perfect for a graph DB as Neo4j.

If you choose option C, you'll have a lot of code that is only doing id translation and synchronization between the two databases. You'd better have a good reason for using two stores like this.

Comment: The reason the PM wants to consider option C is because of performance. He thinks it's a better choice. I'll have to find a way to convince him he is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing some details of your project, but normally you'll have an important performance gain by replacing the many-to-many relational data with edges in Neo4j. This is one of the main reasons for going for a graph db when storing relations.